# Auto select new items in pending changes view

Tags: plasticscm

I am using the Plastic scm version 5.4.16.743, and I am using the VS2015 IDE for development. Since I have upgraded to this version of plastic, every time a new file is add in VS, plastic adds that file to the "Added and Private Items" list but it does not auto select the items to be checked in by default (As it says in plastic documentation).

Does anybody know why plastic doesn't auto select the newly added items for check in as it before?

Is there a way to turn this feature back on?

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio package has two pending changes views:

[image]

- **Pending changes under solution**: It displays only those items that are under the Visual Studio Solution. In this view, added and private items are automatically marked (checked) to be added to source control.
- **Pending changes under workspace**: It diplays all changed and private items in your whole workspace. In this view, added and private items are not marked (checked) to be added automatically, because you could have thousands if you did not configured your ignored filter.

So, when working inside Visual Studio, I recommend you to use always the **pending changes under Solution** to work flawlessly.

Comment: Daniel, Thanks! Yes, in VS I can see that the new file is checked as you described above. But I am used to using the plastic client for last couple of years when there comprehensive plastic VS plug-in wasn't available. It still doesn't answer my question specific to Plastic Client, although you raised a new question, whether should we not use the plastic client but migrate to using VS plugin?

Comment: Hi @Jegan: If I understood correctly, you mean that you expect to find added and private items to be automatically checked for add to source control in the Plastic GUI client? In that case the answer is no. The Plastic GUI never auto selects local changes automatically to prevent the user checking-in not desired changes to the server.

Comment: Yes, the old version auto selects all newly added files and folders in the "Added and Private Items" section in "Pending Changes in Workspace" view, but once you deselect them, they will stay deselected forever. But the latest version some how disabled this feature. It is become an extra effort to select those files especially if I have lots of private items, I could easily miss-out files that supposed to be checked in.

Comment: @Jegan: Unfortunately the new Plastic SCM versions do not auto selects all newly added files and folders automatically to prevent the user checking-in not desired changes to the server. My recommended way of working in this case is correctly configuring the ignored filter, and just clicking the "added category" that autoselects all its children. Hope it helps!